# Die Frage „Wem oder wen?“. Auf welche Weise hilft sie mir?

Tags: learning, grammatical-case

Als ich mit dem Deutschlernen angefangen habe, ist ein typisches Gespräch zwischen mir und meiner Deutschlehrerin ungefähr wie folgt gelaufen:

> Ich: „Der Ball gehört mich.“
>
> Lehrerin: „Hoppla, nicht so schell! *Wen* oder *wem* gehört der Ball?“

Das hat mich immer genervt, denn hätte ich nur die Antwort der Frage gewusst, hätte ich den Satz nie falsch gesagt!

Mir scheint die Situation so zu sein: Ob *wen* oder *wem* gesagt werden muss, wird von dem Kasus bestimmt, aber ob *mich* oder *mir* gesagt werden muss, wird *auch* von dem Kasus bestimmt. Deshalb bin ich keinen Schritt weiter: Ich muss auf jeden Fall den Kasus bestimmen.

Später habe ich derartige Fragen oft gehört, wenn Deutsche den Fall eines Nomens enträtseln wollen. Dieses Ritual stammt vermutlich von der Schulbildung, in der es wie ein pädagogischer Trick benutzt wird, um den Kasus zu lernen. Für mich ergibt die Frage aber immer noch keinen Sinn.

Warum hilft diese Frage dabei, den Kasus zu bestimmen? Gibt es einen logischen Grund, oder dreht es sich um das Sprachgefühl?

Ist es anders, wenn die Frage mit einer Präposition gestellt wird? Beispiel:

> Auf *wen* oder *wem* stehst du?

Beachtet bitte, dass ich nicht nur am Wen- und Wemfall interessiert bin, obwohl das Beispiel nur diese Fälle erwähnt und ich diese Fälle am schwierigsten finde. Das *wer* und *wessen* wäre auch in der Diskussion willkommen.

Comment: @Deve: Danke für die Verbesserungen. Nicht nur verbessert es die Frage, es ist für mich auch eine kostenlose Deutschlektion. :)

Comment: Gern geschehen :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Die Verwendung dieser Fragen ist in den ersten Schuljahren üblich und für Muttersprachler auch hilfreich (interessanterweise war es aber in meiner Schule keineswegs üblich, dass die Lehrerin die richtige und falsche Version zur Auswahl gestellt hat, sondern sie hätte im Eingangsgespräch gesagt: Nicht so schnell. WEM gehört der Ball?).

Als Gründe sehe ich:

Gerade die Verwendung von "mir" und "mich" weicht in Dialekten häufiger von der Hochsprache ab, das ist bei den Fragewörtern eher nicht der Fall.

Der Fall des Objekts soll auch für seltenere Wörter bestimmt werden, die Fragewörter hat aber jedes Kind schon oft verwendet und ist damit viel eher vertraut.

Dass das Zitieren dieser Methode für fremdsprachige Lerner der deutschen Sprache lästig ist, kann ich aber gut nachvollziehen. Was die Methode macht, ist es, die Entscheidung zwischen den beiden Fällen von der tatsächlichen Formenbildung für das konkrete Wort zu trennen.

Comment: Auch Kinder fragen falsch: *"Wen hast Du das gegeben?"*. Ich bekomme das im Moment täglich zu hören - meine Tochter ist 6.

Comment: Es gibt beispiele für den dialektischen Unterschied zwischen *mir* und *mich* im [Link von Takkats Antwort](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,338517,00.html). Und mit dem letzten Satz hast du den Nagel genau auf den Kopf getroffen.

Comment: Die richtige Frage formulieren zu müssen, hilft nicht immer. Ich wuchs in der Nähe von Graz auf, dort wurde in der Alltagssprache kein Genitiv verwendet. Ich wäre daher auch nie auf die Idee gekommen Fragen wie "Wessen Buch ist das?" zu stellen. Ich hätte stattdessen ganz selbstverständlich gefragt: "Wem sein Buch ist das?" Die meiner Meinung nach einzige richtige Antwort wäre gewesen: "Das ist dem Michael sein Buch." Mir und meinen Mitschülern mit dieser Frage-Methode den Genitiv beizubringen hätte also niemals funktioniert.

Answer (score 7):

Es ist (vermutlich auch in anderen Sprachen) einfacher, über einen Anwendungsfall das Sprachgefühl zu aktivieren, als eine grammatikalische Regel abzurufen. Würde mich jemand fragen: "Steht *gehören* mit Dativ oder Akkusativ?", würde ich auch spontan einen Beispielsatz bilden und daraus die grammatikalische Regel ableiten: "Mit Dativ". Ein Muttersprachler wird fast immer die grammatikalische Regel über ihre Anwendung gelernt haben, nicht die Anwendung über die Regel.

Umgekehrt lernt wohl ein Großteil derjenigen, die eine Fremdsprache lernen, anhand der grammatikalischen Regeln (wie bildet man die Tempora, Singular-/Pluralformen etc. pp.). Dann ist es auch naheliegend, dass der "Appell ans Sprachgefühl" ins Leere geht (oh, sehe gerade, thei hat das schon geschrieben...).

Um also die Ausgangsfrage zu beantworten: Jemandem, der Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernt, hilft die Frage "wem/wen" wahrscheinlich gar nicht. Hilft sie, ist das aber ein sehr gutes Zeichen :-) - dann ist das Sprachgefühl bereits sehr gut ausgeprägt!

Interessant übrigens: [leo.org](http://dict.leo.org) hat für **Sprachgefühl** gar keine Übersetzung, sondern sieht den deutschen Begriff auch für das Englische vor...

Answer (score 3):

Die Unterscheidung zwischen Akkusativ und Dativ ist im Deutschen schwierig und fällt auch  Muttersprachlern mitunter schwer. Im [Zwiebelfisch](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,338517,00.html) steht ein amüsanter Artikel zu diesem Thema, hier ein kurzes Zitat:

> Auch im Hochdeutschen ist es längst nicht immer eindeutig. Heißt es "auf sein Recht beharren" oder "auf seinem Recht beharren"? Der Duden lässt hier nur den Dativ gelten. Bei "auf etwas bestehen" geht hingegen beides, man kann "auf seinem Recht bestehen" (wenn man darauf beharrt), und man kann "auf sein Recht bestehen" (wenn man es einfordert). Immer wieder gerate ich ins Grübeln, wenn ich mit der Frage konfrontiert werde, ob es "Er hat ihm auf die Füße getreten" heißt oder "Er hat ihn auf die Füße getreten". Aber auch hier ist beides möglich.

Viele Kinder können diesen Unterschied nicht - sie benutzen überwiegend den Akkusativ - bis sie Schreiben lernen. Beim Hören und Sprechen fällt die Verwendung des Akkusativ auch nicht weiter auf.

Im genannten Beispiel *"auf wen/wem stehst Du?"* ist beides möglich, wenn auch mit anderer Bedeutung:

> Gabi steht auf dem Teppich = *sie steht mit ihren Füßen auf dem Teppich*
>
> Gabi steht auf den Teppich = *sie mag den Teppich sehr*

Comment: Interessant, aber ein bisschen abschweifend. Ich versuche meine Frage ausführlicher zu erklären: Wenn man nicht weiss, ob "auf etwas bestehen" Dativ oder Akkusativ fordert, schreibt manche den Satz um: "Auf wen oder wem bestehe ich?" Diese Umschreibung scheint den Muttersprachlern zu helfen. Warum ist jene Fragen hilfreich?

Comment: Die *wem* oder *wen* Frage hilft meines Erachtens im Einzelfall nicht weiter (man muss den Kasus bereits kennen, um die Frage richtig stellen zu können).

Answer (score 0):

Wenn du die Konstruktion nicht weißt, hilt dir die Frage wem/wen überhaupt nicht. Man muß im Lexikon nachschauen, wie das Verb gehören konstruiert wird: etwas gehört mir (Dativ). Deine Lehrerin hätte dir also sagen müssen, nach "gehören" steht der Dativ der Person. Übrigens genau wie im Englischen: something belongs to me and not: something belongs me.