# Beispiele für Konstruktionen, die sowohl mit Dativ als auch mit Akkusativ funktionieren (und eine unterschiedliche Bedeutung haben)?

Tags: grammatical-case

Wahrscheinlich ist es nicht umsonst ein großes Problem zu lernen, wann Dativ und wann Akkusativ eingesetzt werden (sowohl für erwachsene Deutschlernende als auch für Kinder).

In [Die Frage „Wem oder wen?“. Auf welche Weise hilft sie mir?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1334/die-frage-wem-oder-wen-auf-welche-weise-hilft-sie-mir) findet sich ein Beispiel, in dem wirklich ein semantischer Unterschied besteht: "Ich stehe auf Dich" vs. "Ich stehe auf Dir."

Es wollen mir partout keine sinnvollen weiteren Beispiele einfallen, in denen Verben sowohl mit Dativ als auch mit Akkusativ stehen können. Gibt es noch welche (mal abgesehen vom wundervollen Berliner "Ick liebe dir")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es gibt einige Verben, die sowohl mit einem Dativ- als auch mit einem Akkusativobjekt verwendet werden können bzw. müssen. Dazu zählen vor allem Verben des *Gebens, Nehmens und Sagens,* zum Beispiel: *geben, leihen, wünschen, schenken.*

Beispiel:

> "Wem machst du Geschenke?" – "Ich schenke den Kindern" *(Dativ)*
>   "Was schenkst du ihnen?" – "Ich schenke Spielzeug." *(Akkusativ)*

Normalerweise verwendet man in diesen Fällen Dativ- und Akkusativobjekt im selben Satz. Im Dativ steht in der Regel die andere Person, die etwas "empfängt"; im Akkusativ steht die Sache:

> Der Weihnachtsmann schenkt den Kindern Spielzeug.

Hier eine List mit Verben mit Dativ- und Akkusativergänzungen:

> anvertrauen, beantworten, beweisen, borgen, bringen, empfehlen, erklären, erlauben, erzählen, geben, glauben, kaufen, leihen, liefern, mitteilen, rauben, reichen, sagen, schenken, schicken, schreiben, senden, stehlen, überlassen, verbieten, verschweigen, versprechen, wegnehmen, wünschen, zeigen

Außerdem gibt es Verben, die mit einer Präpositionsergänzung verwendet werden; es gibt [einige Präpositionen, die den 3. und 4. Fall verlangen können](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/2Kasus.html), zum Beispiel:

*hinter*

> Ich laufe hinter dem Stadion. (genau dort laufe ich immer – "wo?")
>   Ich laufe hinter das Stadion. (dorthin laufe ich – "wohin?")

Comment: Danke für die Zusammenfassung! Die Antwort ist bislang der Favorit...

Answer (score 5):

Im gegebenen Beispiel ist der Akkusativ oder Dativ kein Objekt des Verbs, sondern gehört zum Vorwort "auf".

Alle örtlichen Vorwörter im Deutschen haben das Muster:

Wo? Dativ (Der Ort, an dem etwas stattfindet.)
Wohin? Akkusativ (Der Ort, wo die Handlung hinführt.)

Dieses Muster kann mit Verben, die den Ort im übertragenen Sinn verwenden, natürlich abstraktere Bedeutungsunterschiede hervorrufen.

Answer (score 4):

Bei deinem Beispiel ist der Sinn unterschiedlich.

Bei "Ich versichere dir, daß ich dir treu bin." vs. "Ich versichere dich meiner Treue." wäre das anders.

Also, jetzat:

- Ich versichere dir, daß ...
- Ich versichere dich gegen Hochwasser.

Comment: Ich meinte auch Beispiele, bei denen der Sinn unterschiedlich ist. Habe meine Überschrift schlecht gewählt...

Comment: Ok, dann: "Ich versichere dir, daß X" und "Ich versichere dich gegen X."

Comment: Aber nicht `jetzat` - nicht in Schriftdeutsch! Ich protestiere energisch! (Ich überlege noch, ob ich ein Smilie hier setzen kann, soll und darf.)

Comment: Smile wäre angemessen, denn was immer du unter Schriftdeutsch verstehen magst, so zeigt doch dein Protest, daß du die Bedeutung von "jetzat" sehr wohl kennst.

Comment: Aber bitte doch keine Smileys im „Schriftdeutschen“.

Answer (score 1):

neben (und andere Ortsangaben):

```
Ich falle neben dich.
Ich falle neben dir.
```

Comment: Super. Da ergibt sich ein Muster: "Ich spucke neben dich" - "Ich spucke neben dir". "Ich warte auf dich" - "Ich warte auf dir"...

Comment: @Olaf: Beim Warten ist "auf + Akkusativ" allerdings keine Ortsangabe.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: Stimmt. Und bei "Ich stehe auf Dich" auch nicht... dennoch lassen sich nach dem Muster einige Fälle finden.

Comment: auf + Akkusativ ist NIE eine Ortsangabe.